# Jquery code not firing inside user control aspx

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the following Jquery in my user control which is loaded onto the page, however the jquery is not firing at all:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("div.holder").jPages({
            containerID: "itemContainer",
            perPage: 2,
            first: false,
            previous: "span.arrowPrev",
            next: "span.arrowNext",
            last: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have tried stripping this out and just using an alert when inside of document.ready but this still does not fire. How can i get this code to execute inside of a user control in aspx?

And simply this is the html i am using:

```
<div class="eng-container">
<!-- navigation holder -->
<div class="holder">
</div>

<!-- wrapped custom buttons for easier styling -->
<div class="customBtns">

    <span class="arrowPrev"></span>
    <span class="arrowNext"></span>
</div>
<ul id="itemContainer">
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

There are no obvious errors with the code i can see.

**EDIT**

http://jsfiddle.net/p4LES/1/

**EDIT 2**
Heres the pastebin link for the code, it is quite long though for the whole page. At line 185 my script begins and my HTML code related to it.

http://pastebin.com/szknh76v

**UPDATE**

I've tried moving the jQuery code in question to the main.Master file for my project which looks to have fixed the problem in question and it is now firing. Although I have no clue as to why the javascript would not fire within the control.

Comment: The alert which you talked about worked that means?

Comment: No the alert with a simple message didnt fire

Comment: div.holder does not contain itemContainer. Check your end tags.

Comment: Have you referenced a jquery lib anywhere on the page?

Comment: moving the div .holder end tag doesnt effect the outcome, the code still doesnt fire

Comment: The jquery library at the end of the document, would this make a difference? Seeing as I am using Document.Ready the code only fires after the page has loaded?

Comment: Hi have got a jsfiddle with the exact same code working just fine, it doesnt work inside of my aspx control though. I'll add the link to the fiddle in the question

Comment: yes, I have checked your previous question.. http://jsfiddle.net/p4LES/1/ .. will you add that script portion after library defined..

Comment: @ShaunakShukla Yes my script portion is added after my jquery library and the required js script.

Comment: Can you post the page source in a pastebin link? Are there any errors in your browsers dev console?

Comment: @DGibbs Sure, I'll get that now

Comment: @DGibbs edited main post with link

Comment: @user3793198 Few things - you're referencing two different versions of the jquery lib on the same page.. `jquery-1.9.0.min.js` and `1.11.1/jquery.min.js`. Try moving `jPages.js` to the bottom of the page where the rest of your scripts are loaded (why are you loading them at the bottom of the page?). Whats with the script block above the `1.11.1/jquery.min.js` reference? Check your browsers dev console (F12 in chrome), are there any errors (red X in top right corner)?

Comment: Better look into this line : `<script type="text/javascript" src="///ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: @DGibbs I've attempted to recity what you have suggested. i've removed the 1.11 library, and moved jPages to the bottom. I'me not to sure about the scripts above the 1.11 reference, they are from another dev, and pulled in when the aspx default page is constructed. With regards to the developer console in chrome i notice no red 'x' or errors. although in the network tab a 404 not found is fired for `jquery.min.map
ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery`

Comment: @j809 I've now removed that reference but still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I created a new HTML page and this worked for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jPages.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("div.holder").jPages({
                containerID: "itemContainer",
                perPage: 2,
                first: false,
                previous: "span.arrowPrev",
                next: "span.arrowNext",
                last: false
            });
            alert("myMsg");
        });
    </script>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="eng-container">
<!-- navigation holder -->
<div class="holder">
</div>

<!-- wrapped custom buttons for easier styling -->
<div class="customBtns">

    <span class="arrowPrev"></span>
    <span class="arrowNext"></span>
</div>
<ul id="itemContainer">
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```